# Merging two non-overlapping pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe with a pair of columns where, on every row, one cell is a nan and the other is not. It looks like this:

|  | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | nan |
| 1 | 8 | nan |
| 2 | nan | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | nan |
| 4 | nan | 2 |
| 5 | nan | 6 |

I would like to merge these two columns in one without the nans:

|  | Var1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 |

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `df.max(1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), setting `values` parameter to another Series.

```
df['Var1'].fillna(df['Var2'], inplace=True)
df['Var1']

#    Var1
# 0  3
# 1  8
# 2  6
# 3  4
# 4  2
# 5  6
```

Comment: `.drop('Var2',1)` to match OP output

Answer (score 0):

You might harness `numpy` for this task following way

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':[np.nan,2,np.nan,4],'v2':[1,np.nan,3,np.nan]})
df['v'] = np.where(np.isnan(df.v1),df.v2,df.v1)
print(df)
```

output

```
    v1   v2    v
0  NaN  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  3.0
3  4.0  NaN  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the frame which will drop the `NaN`s by default. Then you can construct a new frame with its values:

```
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack().to_numpy(), columns=["Var1"])
>>> new_df

   Var1
0   3.0
1   8.0
2   6.0
3   4.0
4   2.0
5   6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```py
df = df.transform(sorted, key=pd.isna, axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how="all")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      ID  var1
0  103.0  11.0
1  104.0  16.0
2  105.0  71.0
3  106.0   2.0
3  107.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method - if you only have two columns.

```
df.assign(Var1=df.sum(axis=1))[['Var1']]

   Var1
0   3.0
1   8.0
2   6.0
3   4.0
4   2.0
5   6.0
```